# Why no sqlite error codes

Tags: android, sqlite

Why am I not getting error codes for SQLite failures?  I am trying to create a database and getting the following stacktrace (well, the top of the trace):

```
E/SqliteDatabaseCpp(11974): sqlite3_open_v2
("/mnt/sdcard/myapp/mydatabase.db", &handle, 6, NULL) failed
E/SQLiteDatabase(11974): Failed to open the database. closing it.
E/SQLiteDatabase(11974): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file
E/SQLiteDatabase(11974):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
```

My code works in the emulator, works on a Nexus 7, but fails on another device

```
  public SQLiteDatabase openOrCreateDatabase (String name, int mode,
                                              SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory,
                                              DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler)
  {
    File f = getDatabasePath (name);
    System.out.println ("opening db: " + f.getPath());
    return super.openOrCreateDatabase (f.getPath(), mode, factory, errorHandler);
  }
```

Here's a full log from a second try.  It's a little different than the first, but still no error code.

```
W/dalvikvm( 3314): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a801f8)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.myapp.myapp/com.myapp.myapp.main.MainActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:812)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:579)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1013)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:986)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1051)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:782)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at com.myapp.myapp.dbaccess.DatabaseContext.openOrCreateDatabase(DbHelper.java:63)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at com.myapp.myapp.dbaccess.DbHelper.getDb(DbHelper.java:184)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at com.myapp.myapp.dbaccess.DbHelper.getZRoot(DbHelper.java:650)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at com.myapp.myapp.dbaccess.ZNodeCache.getRequiredNodes(ZNodeCache.java:37)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at com.myapp.myapp.dbaccess.ZNodeCache.<init>(ZNodeCache.java:22)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at com.myapp.myapp.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:81)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3314):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: "Why am I not getting error codes for SQLite failures?" That looks like a Java failure not a SQLite failure, post all of your LogCat errors. What minimum API are you using?

Comment: Unforutnately (or maybe fortunately) I can't repro the error anymore.  I unplugged the kyocera and worked on the nexus 7 for a while.  When I went back to the kyocera, perhaps it did some more initialization (it's brand new).  Any my app successfully created its db and ran.  I wish I knew what caused the failure.  Maybe I'll try a factory reset and see what that does.

Comment: Ok, I did a factory reset.  Tried again and it failed.  However the factory reset did not erase the sdcard (leaving my db intact) so that may have affected the behavior - you'll see the log is slightly different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this was stupid.  If you have your device connected and you select a "USB storage" connection, the sdcard becomes inaccessable.  Moral of story: don't enable "USB storage" if your app accesses the sdcard.

Still, Android should emit an error code - I'll file a bug.